# Leray-Ohya Hyperbolic System of PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde

I have a second order PDE system. I calculated symbol of the operator and considered the determinant. This determinant is not a hyperbolic polynomial with respect to any vector in R^4. I came across a paper which mentions Leray-Ohya notion of hyperbolicity. Apart from their original paper in French( which unfortunately I can't read!), is there a readily available reference that discusses this notion? Also, how does it differ from the usual notion of hyperbolicity as discussed, for example, in Hormander's Analysis of Linear PDOs (Vol.2, Chapter 12)?

Comment: Have a look at Appendix IV of the book "General Relativity and the Einstein Equations" by Yvonne Choquet-Bruhat (Oxford, 2009). It has a brief discussion on Leray-Ohya systems. Basically, for these systems well-posedness and finite propagation speed hold only in certain Gevrey classes.

Comment: When you say "not a hyperbolic polynomial" do you mean in the strict sense (which requires the right number of distinct roots) or in the weak sense (which requires the right number of roots, when counted with multiplicity)? Leray-Ohya implies hyperbolicity in the weak sense.

Comment: I had my characteristic polynomial as a product of two polynomials, one with multiplicities and hyperbolic. The other polynomial was somewhat scary looking. However, I was able to show that, that too is hyperbolic. So, I believe, I can say that the PDE operator is weakly hyperbolic in the sense of L-O. Thanks for your help :)